# How to print the position and value of a nested array using recursion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a simple question

have a nested list using recursion I have to print all the nested array as well as the value of main array  .

**In-put**

```
var list = ['a', ['a','b','c',['a','b','c']],'b', 'c'];
printList('foo',list);
```

**Out-put**

```
foo.0.a
foo.1.0.a
foo.1.1.b
foo.1.2.c
foo.1.3.0.a
foo.1.3.1.b
foo.2.b
foo.3.c
```

But I am able to print only till one level deep

```js
var list = ['a', ['a','b','c',['a','b','c']],'b', 'c'];
   var printList = function(name,list){

     for(var i=0;i< list.length;i++){

         if(Array.isArray(list[i]))
             {
               printList(name+'.'+i,list[i]);

             }
             else{

                 document.write(name+'.'+i+'.'+list[i]+'<br/>');
              
             }
              
     }
   }

   printList('foo',list);
```

I have added the code snippet have a look

Thanks

Comment: So how should the desired output look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @VisioN its not printing all the element of the array , If you see it is printing only till the end of the first array that is `foo.1.x.vlaues`  it did not print `foo.2.0.b` and `foo.3.0.c`

Comment: @Teemu I am beginner in js do not understand how that question is related with my question

Comment: Undeclared variables assignment binds it to the global scope,typical JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the i in the for loop became a global variable, making it loose its value once in the recursion.

add `var i;` declaration before for loop in the function and the issue should be solved.

```
var list = ['a', ['a','b','c',['a','b','c']],'b', 'c'];
    var printList = function(name,list){
        var i;
        for(i=0;i< list.length;i++) {
            if(Array.isArray(list[i])) {
                printList(name+'.'+i,list[i]);
            } else {
                  document.write(name+'.'+i+'.'+list[i]+'<br/>');
            }
        }
    }

    printList('foo',list);
```